# Deserialize classes without serialversionuid

Tags: java

I have a class that implements serializable interface. I am trying to deserialize an object that serialized and stored by another application. The object that stored by another application is created by a class similar to below -

```
// does not have serialversionuid defined.
public class Pet implements Serializable {
    private count;       
    private date;

    // getters & setters
}
```

I have a similar class defined in my application. Mine doesn't have serialversionuid defined as well. When I try to deserialize this object , I see an error similar to this -

> IO error occurred while unmarshalling java.io.InvalidClassException:
> local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
> -3565652537049376317, local class serialVersionUID = -4242367052120288379

I don't have control over the class that is serializing and storing the data. Is there a way for me to make changes to my class so that it can deserialize the object?

Comment: I believe that classes might be different, do you have access to see exactly what class is being used does it have the same structure ?

Comment: Thanks @EduardoDennis. You are correct. There were 2 additional methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the section 4.6 in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) specification, if a serializable class doesn't specify the `serialVersionUID`, JVM chooses one on its own based on the class detail. However the algorithm it chooses (described in the link above) is highly sensitive to the class details. Also, it may depend on the compiler implementation as well because the algorithm directly works on the stream of bytes that reflect the class definition.

In your case, since you get the invalid class version error during demarshalling, it means one of the following 2 things:

1. Your class, although you think is very close to the class used by the other application, is still slightly different. Check the algorithm again. It is highly sensitive on the class detail.
2. The object that is serialized by the other application was created from a class definition generated by a different compiler.

In order for you to be able to deserialize that object, you must examine the above 2 possibilities and take actions to remove the disparities.

Comment: Thanks @VHS. I see that my class has 2 extra methods.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the issue. The serialVersionUID's don't match because the classes are different.

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo Dennis

Comment: That *is* the issue, and the difference in `serialVersionUID` is how it was detected.

Comment: @EJP the original post he believes the issue was he hadn't defined the serial version so that is why they were different. Notice the first comment how he understood what I was saying and thanked me in the comments.